# How can I get the current url

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I need to get the current url, like https://www.mypage.com/subfolder/iamhere.html

I know that I can get the templatePath using getCurrentTemplatePath(), but I need the url and I don't know how to do that.

I searched in google and stackoverflow, but I always ended up either with non cfml code or the templatePath.

Comment: If you have debugging turned on, look at your cgi variables.

Comment: Use the CGI scope

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137347/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-coldfusion-i-am-getting-home-page-url-index-cfm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current page URL in coldfusion ? I am getting home\_page\_URL/index.cfm while fetching current page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137347/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-coldfusion-i-am-getting-home-page-url-index-cfm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample URL you give is an HTML page.  For that, you'd need Javascript.  Something like:

```
var addr = window.location.href;
```

For ColdFusion, be sure you're using code on an actual CFML page.  For instance:
https://www.mypage.com/subfolder/iamhere.cfm

If this is the case, like others have said, you should use the CGI scope.  As an example:

```
<cfset addr = (cgi.SERVER_PORT IS 443?'https':'http') & "://" & cgi.HTTP_HOST & cgi.HTTP_URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the pieces are available in the CGI scope. dump(CGI)